# Button / Change border color C# when active an set back to default when other button is active

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have three buttons. Once I click on one it will change its border color to different color and show its active, but to set it default i have to click on the button again. All of these three buttons represent different action and they cant be running simutionasly for the user. Do you know what to do to set back to default border color of button 1 if button 2 is clicked?

Created my byttons in xamarin and this is the code behind.

I tried to create a separated method for that but i cant locate the buttons.

```
 protected void EnglishToCzech_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Button englishtoczech = (Button)sender;
     if (englishtoczech.BorderColor.Equals(Color.Default)) 
         english.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#da2c43");
     else 
         englishtoczech.BorderColor = Color.Default;  
 }

 protected void CzechToEnglish_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Button czechtoenglish = (Button)sender;
     if (czechtoenglish.BorderColor.Equals(Color.Default)) 
         english.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#da2c43");
     else
         czechtoenglish.BorderColor = Color.Default;
 }

 protected  void English_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Button english = (Button)sender;
     if (english.BorderColor.Equals(Color.Default))
         english.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#da2c43");
     else
         english.BorderColor = Color.Default;
 }
```

Comment: It seems there is a problem in your code sample that is every button click changes `english.BorderColor` this seems typo because this will not build. I have assumed the correct one and used that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if I understand you correctly, you can reset the color of all in each click.
First you need to assign names to buttons. If you use XAML add `x:Name` attribute and give them names. I suppose you name them `englishtoczech`, `czechtoenglish` and `english` but you can name them anything. The convention is camel case.
Then you can use them in your code behind like this:

```
 protected void EnglishToCzech_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (englishtoczech.BorderColor.Equals(Color.Default))
     {
         englishtoczech.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#da2c43");
         czechtoenglish.BorderColor = Color.Default;
         english.BorderColor = Color.Default;
     }
     else 
         englishtoczech.BorderColor = Color.Default;  
 }

 protected void CzechToEnglish_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (czechtoenglish.BorderColor.Equals(Color.Default)) 
     {
         czechtoenglish.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#da2c43");
         englishtoczech.BorderColor = Color.Default; 
         english.BorderColor = Color.Default;
     }
     else
         czechtoenglish.BorderColor = Color.Default;
 }

 protected void English_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (english.BorderColor.Equals(Color.Default))
     {
         english.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#da2c43");
         englishtoczech.BorderColor = Color.Default; 
         czechtoenglish.BorderColor = Color.Default;
     }
     else
         english.BorderColor = Color.Default;
 }
```

This is a pretty good simple approach but, two things you should consider:

1. You shouldn't build your logic over button border colors and it is good to have some variable holding the state of system.
2. In more advanced scenarios if you are a professional I strongly recommend that you read MVVM and try that in a Xamarin project. That makes your life a lot easier down the path

Let me elaborate more on the first point.

You will set the border colors here but nothing happens. I think later on another event you will check the border color of buttons and do some logic with them.

This way you have built your logic over border colors. You can create an `enum`

```
public enum State
{
    None,
    English,
    EnglishToCzech,
    CzechToEnglish
}
```

And then in your code bihind add a variable of that enum

```
private State state = State.None;
```

And finally set the state in each button click accordingly.

This is just an example I hope it helps.

Comment: HI Emand, thank you. I cant do this as I cant acces thr other two buttons in the different method. I am getting a red underline all over

Comment: Oh right. Use name on the buttons. I will fix the answer now

Comment: And thank you for your advise, so by having some variable you mean for each button or could please explain to me in more details or point me in the right direction. I am a begginer as you can see. And I will definitely have a look on MVVM.

Comment: Your welcome. If you accept the answer I will be rewarded. Also others will know that this issue is fixed. Thanks.